# How can config Nginx properly, when base property added inside of Vite.config.js?

Tags: nginx, vuejs3, vite

I am using Vue 3 and Vite as build tool. and defined the base property inside of Vite.config as follows:

```
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/main",
  ///

});
```

and also, my nginx config before adding base inside Vite.config is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    charset     utf-8;  
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

All things work correctly before adding base property, but when it defined, after building , the sources of build project are not recognized and following error appears by nginx:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

how can handle it and modify my nginx config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem, by updating the Nginx config as follows:

```
  server {
    listen 8080;
    charset     utf-8;  
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

      location /main {
         alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /main/index.html;
    }
}
```