# React served on nginx with base url, from container - nginx tries to search in custom prefix path when I use location

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I have such a Dockerfile for my react app:

```
FROM node:16 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.23.2-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/run/nginx.pid /usr/share/nginx/html /var/cache/nginx /var/log/nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d
USER nginx
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I have such a nginx.conf

```
server_tokens off;
server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  localhost;
    location /todofastapi {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

I build the image with command: `docker build -t react-app .`
I run the containerised app: `docker run --name kotek -d -p 8000:8000 react-app`

Nginx stands up allright
But when I go to `locahlost:8000/todofastapi` or `locahlost:8000/todofastapi/` I see the default nginx error page.
[image]

I want this app to be accessible from `locahlost:8000/todofastapi` or `locahlost:8000/todofastapi/`

Here are the logs

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [warn] 1#1: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.2
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 11.2.1 20220219 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.49-linuxkit-pr
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2023/09/19 19:04:54 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2023:19:04:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
2023/09/19 19:04:58 [error] 30#30: *2 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2023/09/19 19:04:59 [error] 30#30: *2 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2023:19:04:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2023:19:05:03 +0000] "GET /todofastapi HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
2023/09/19 19:05:03 [error] 30#30: *2 open() "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /todofastapi HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2023/09/19 19:05:51 [error] 30#30: *2 open() "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /todofastapi HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2023:19:05:51 +0000] "GET /todofastapi HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
2023/09/19 19:06:27 [error] 30#30: *2 open() "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /todofastapi HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2023:19:06:27 +0000] "GET /todofastapi HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2023:19:06:27 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "http://localhost:8000/todofastapi" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
2023/09/19 19:06:27 [error] 30#30: *2 open() "/etc/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000", referrer: "http://localhost:8000/todofastapi"
2023/09/19 19:06:29 [error] 30#30: *2 open() "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /todofastapi/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2023:19:06:29 +0000] "GET /todofastapi/ HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: just a thought, what happens if you go to `locahlost:8000/todofastapi/dist`?

Comment: If its worth anything: If I just replace `location /todofastapi/` with `location /` it works

Comment: @dave the same - nginx 404

Comment: But this thing is interesting:  `open() "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory),`

Comment: Ok, I set up nginx on my machine, and go similar error. Since its not dockerised linux system but mac, I get different error for 404 - `2023/09/19 22:20:49 [error] 24912#0: *1 "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/nginx/1.25.2/html/todofastapi/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1,`

It indicates it falling back to default for some reason.

Comment: If you remove `USER nginx` in your Dockerfile, does that make any difference?

Comment: (I might delete everything after the two `COPY` lines.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found an answer.
My nginx conf file looks like this now:

```
server_tokens off;
server {
    listen       8000;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location /todofastapi {
        alias   /usr/share/nginx/html;

        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

I found help here [How can config Nginx properly, when base property added inside of Vite.config.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76602107/how-can-config-nginx-properly-when-base-property-added-inside-of-vite-config-js)

It requires using both `alias` and `root` directives, `alias` inside, `root` outside `location`